# query an array of object in an array of object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, nosql

I have this document model below. I want to query by attributes with name and value (I know the name and value of attribute eg. `{"name": "Renk", "value": "Kirmizi"}`). All I need is the document. I dont need index of variant or attribute, just document's itself. My purpose is not to get attributes or variants. I am querying across all documents. I hope you don't understand me wrong

```json
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5febdbf5d71b7ca4eef06cc5"),
    "variants" : [
        {
            "id" : "xtb2E3PVNitmh5xhuRAFNd",
            "attributes" : [
                {
                    "name" : "Renk",
                    "value" : "Kirmizi"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Beden",
                    "value" : "36"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Yaka Tipi",
                    "value" : "V Yaka"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "aP6CDPsgVLxTLgY5D6bTm9",
            "attributes" : [
                {
                    "name" : "Renk",
                    "value" : "Kirmizi"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Beden",
                    "value" : "38"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Yaka Tipi",
                    "value" : "V Yaka"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "b3mLCJXe6ae8HhNAY8dCPW",
            "attributes" : [
                {
                    "name" : "Renk",
                    "value" : "Mavi"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Beden",
                    "value" : "38"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Yaka Tipi",
                    "value" : "V Yaka"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id" : "hYrANxJTbXmEYDUjtFpEKT",
            "attributes" : [
                {
                    "name" : "Renk",
                    "value" : "Mavi"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Beden",
                    "value" : "36"
                },
                {
                    "name" : "Yaka Tipi",
                    "value" : "V Yaka"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updatedDate" : NumberLong(1609292789)
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: try `{ "variants.attributes.name": "Renk", "variants.attributes.value": "Kirmizi" }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work. This will search exact key and value pair :

```
 {'variants.attributes': { 'name' : 'Renk', 'value' : 'Kirmizi' }}
```

[Result on MongoDB Compass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFNAi.png)

Note: Be careful when do this { "variants.attributes.name": "Renk", "variants.attributes.value": "Kirmizi" }. The object is flatten so this query means find any document contains key 'Renk' and value 'Kirmizi' but 'Renk' and 'Kirmizi' can be in different objects!

Read official document from Mongo for more details https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-array-of-documents/